# Forcefully add dimension to NumPy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have a four-dimensional data in array `trainAll` of shape *N × H × W × 3*. I need to separate it so I did

```
X_train = trainAll[:,:,:,1]
Y_train = trainAll[:,:,:,1:3]
```

As expected, `Y_train.shape` was *N × H × W × 2*.

But `X_train.shape` is *N × H × W* because the last dimension has just size 1.
But neural network need **four dimensional** array, so it should look like

*N × H × W **× 1***

The amazing thing is, if I do `trainAll[:,:,:,2:3]` then I get `N*H*W*1` but I want the first dimension separated, not the last.

Honestly, I was unable to google because I did not know what to ask. So can any one help me out, so that I can not only separate first dimension but also `shape` is *N × H × W **× 1*** instead of *N × H × W*  ?

Comment: these are numpy arrays as I printed out them as `aray.shape`

Comment: my bad, I was doing this `trainAll[:,:,:,1]` instead of `trainAll[:,:,:,0]` but I have found a solution by `trainAll[:,:,:,0:1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add a new axis as the desired dimension. (Here, as the fourth dimension).

```
X_train = trainAll[:, :, :, 0]
X_train = X_train[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
# now, X_train.shape will be N * H * W * 1
```

The reason why you don't get them at the first place when you slice them is because slice hands the result as `(n,)` when using a single index and you make it `(n, 1)` by adding a new axis.

Comment: Even though I was able to do it in single line but I accepted answer for "because slice hands the result as `(n,)`"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out but still do not know if my answer is right. I wanted to know the python way to do it and What is happening when shape is shifted to `N*H*W` instead of `N*H*W*1`

**Solution:** `trainAll[:,:,:,0:1]` so instead of `trainAll[:,:,:,1]` picking it up just slice it

Comment: That's why I would have suggested, too. Alternatively, you could use [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Comment: Or else, `X_train = trainAll[:, :, :, 0]`

Comment: @kmario23 the problem with your solution is `arr.shape` become `N*H*W` while I need it as `N*H*W*1`. which I did by slicing array

Comment: @kmario23 and I do not know and want to know why output shape changes to `N*h*w` instead of `N*h*w*1`

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bit of the solution. the correct one is `X_train = trainAll[:, :, :, 0]; X_train = X_train[:, :, :, np.newaxis]`

Answer (score 0):

I have found following and it works much better: `tf.expand_dims` [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims), to reduce dimension instead use: `tf.squeeze()` here tf refers to `tensorflow`